# Index in function causing error with function has no attribute getitim

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a python beginner and I am attempting to write a function which computes the nearest neighbours of a lattice point, and am recieving the following error:

> lattice[x, (y - 1) % N] + lattice[x, (y + 1) % N]
>
> TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Any solutions I've found online seem to be to do with passing a function instead of its results, but I can't see how that is happening here.

Here is my code:

```
def lattice(N):
    lattice = np.random.rand(N,N)
    lattice = np.where(lattice <= 0.5, 1,-1)


def nearestneighbours(lattice, x, y):
    return lattice[(x - 1) % N, y] + lattice[(x + 1) % N, y] + \
       lattice[x, (y - 1) % N] + lattice[x, (y + 1) % N]
```

Comment: You are trying to access to a **certain data** (here, a function) using **indexation**. Indexes are used to access values in **iterable** data such as **lists** or **dicts**. A function is not an iterable data (exceptions for generators, but forget about that for the moment), a function is a **box** that receives an **input**, and spits an **output**. To access your function, you will need to use parenthesis `()` in order to pass arguments to it.

Comment: Is there a way to modify my lattice function so that it returns a variable name which I can then use in the nearest neighbor function and access with indexation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't reuse and overwrite function and variable names.
- You should make sure that `lattice` returns the array it creates
- There is some inconsistency. Why does `lattice` accept `N` as an argument but 
  `nearestneighbours` accesses the global variable?

```
def lattice(n):
    arr = np.random.rand(n, n)
    arr = np.where(arr <= 0.5, 1, -1)
    return arr


def nearestneighbours(arr, n, x, y):
    return arr[(x - 1) % n, y] + arr[(x + 1) % n, y] + \
       arr[x, (y - 1) % n] + arr[x, (y + 1) % n]

N = 5
lat = lattice(5)
print nearestneighbours(lat, N, 2, 3) 
# 0
```